# Jenkins polling doesn't detect commits in Github

Tags: git, jenkins, github, jenkins-plugins, polling

I am currently using the "Poll SCM" option in Jenkins with the poll frequency set to 1 minute for now. My goal is to trigger the build job when the polling detects a commit in Github. However, despite committing to "Feature" branch multiple times, the polling doesn't detect the commit. It continually displays message similar to this:

```
Started on May 18, 2018 4:51:00 PM
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision 
ecf20b8hhh2f3d63b5809mle268024500364f2fb 
(refs/remotes/origin/feature/template-api)
> /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
Setting http proxy: surf.proxy.company:80
> /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h https://github.developer.company.com/my- 
project.git # timeout=10
Found 3 remote heads on https://github.developer.company.com/my-project.git
Done. Took 3.7 sec
No changes
```

My pipeline script is as below:

```
node {
   stage('Preparation') {
      git (
          poll: true,
          branch: 'feature/template-api',
          credentialsId: '8u56qwcf-e74e-44z3-9437-c81b19cd3a29',
          url: 'https://github.developer.company.com/my-project.git'
      )
   }
}
```

Within my Jenkins' configuration, I have only "poll SCM" selected. How do I detect changes within Github and trigger the build process?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want your branch name to be `'origin/feature/template-api'`.